# What Bot-Lane combination counters nunu-kog?

Tags: league-of-legends

How do you beat a nunu-kog lane? You lose if you have even farm, and its hard to harass them without taking more damage.

Answer (score 1):

The Kog'Maw-Nunu bot lane can be very devastating. Kog'Maw has some insane range due to his abilities and a slow. Nunu can give Kog'Maw increased movement speed and attack speed and also has two slows (one of which is AoE)

The key to countering this lane is to counter Kog'maw. However, there really is no strong counter against him. Some champions that do well against Kog'maw are:

- **Graves**; he can push the lane fairly quickly forcing Kog'maw to have to last hit under his tower. he can also do burst damage very well. (However, Nunu's Blood Boil makes it easier for Kog'Maw to push back)
- **Tristana**; her range is very large late game, and she has a gap closer and burst damage allowing her to avoid being kited by the slows (both Nunu's and Kog'maw's)
- **Ashe**; her slow allows her to be able to kite Kog'maw, and her ultimate can set up ganks to shut down the lane early on.

One very important thing to remember: **Do Not Feed The Kog'Maw!** If Kog'Maw can get some early kills he WILL snowball and destroy your team.

Some information taken from a very useful guide by Crs Cop:

> http://www.lolpro.com/guides/kogmaw/221-kogmaw-guide-duo-bot